# Toastr onhidden function only success messages

Tags: jquery, toastr

I am using the toastr library and have this code:

```
toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": true,
  "newestOnTop": true,
  "progressBar": true,
  "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
  "preventDuplicates": true,
  "showDuration": 400,
  "hideDuration": 400,
  timeOut: 2500,
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut",
  "newestOnTop": true,
  "onHidden": function() { console.log("HIDE") }
}
```

If the message will disappear (hide) a function will start.
This works fine ! But is there a option, that the onhidden function will only start if I do a toastr.success message?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the `toastr` global callback and check the notifications which You are interested in:

```
function toastrActions(response) {
    if(response.state == 'hidden') {
        console.log("Toastr #",response.toastId,"is hidden. Type:",response.map.type);
    }
}

toastr.subscribe(toastrActions);
```